# CSS pseudo element is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I created a new style to show errors or any message.

```css
input{
  min-width:350px;
  padding:10px;
}
.paswd_info_wrap.quick_note_error {
    background: #f77777;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    border-left: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    max-width:350px;
    font-size:1.2em
}
.paswd_info_wrap {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #efefef;
}
.paswd_info_wrap.quick_note_error:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 10px solid #ff000000;
    border-left: 10px solid #ffffff00;
    border-top: 10px solid #f77777;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    top: -10px;
    transform: rotate( 180deg);
    z-index: 10;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px red);
}
.paswd_info_wrap.quick_note_error::after {
    right: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    top: auto;
    left: calc(50% + 40px);
}
.quick_note_error::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 10px solid #ff000000;
    border-left: 10px solid #ffffff00;
    border-top: 10px solid #f77777;
    left: 0px;
    top: -10px;
    transform: rotate( 180deg);
    z-index: 10;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px red);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="write password">
<div class="paswd_info_wrap quick_note_error">
  <div class="paswd_err">Password is not given correct.</div>
</div>
```

I want to add text **Error** in bottom right as given below in an image.
[image: output]
I have tried to find solution by replacing `content:''` with `content: 'Error'` (in `CSS`) but it is not working as expected.

### IGNORE THIS -

*It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.*

Comment: If you get a message saying _“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”_, then that means you are supposed to do exactly _that_ - add more details, or reduce the amount of code – and _not_ add filler content.

Comment: @CBroe Is here any user who does not able to understand my question ?

Comment: That is not the point, the point was, that you please do not add _random_ stuff, just to weasel your way around such validations & checks. They have been put into place for a reason.

Comment: But I didn't able to think what was more needed information for this question. That's why I added some random words (like lorem ipsum).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a combo of `clip-path` and giving explicit `height` to the `::after` pseudo element with minimal `padding`,`text-align`,`box-shadow` changes and not relying on `border`,`drop-shadow`. The following should work for you :-

```css
input{
  min-width:350px;
  padding:10px;
}
.paswd_info_wrap.quick_note_error {
    background: #f77777;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    border-left: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    max-width:350px;
    font-size:1.2em
}
.paswd_info_wrap {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #efefef;
}
.paswd_info_wrap.quick_note_error:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 10px solid #ff000000;
    border-left: 10px solid #ffffff00;
    border-top: 10px solid #f77777;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    top: -10px;
    transform: rotate( 180deg);
    z-index: 10;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px red);
}
.paswd_info_wrap.quick_note_error::after {
    right: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    top: 100%;
    left: calc(50% + 40px);
}

.quick_note_error::after {
    content: 'Error';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: -10px;
    padding-right:5%;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    text-align:right;
    height:10px;
    clip-path: polygon(9% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 91% 100%);
    background:#f77777;
    font-size:10px;
    transform: rotate( 180deg);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #f34c4c;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="write password">
<div class="paswd_info_wrap quick_note_error">
  <div class="paswd_err">Password is not given correct.</div>
</div>
```

You can experiment with **clip path's** here as well for more precision - https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: `Clip-path` really clips my requirements. So I think I will have to add another child element to 'paswd_info_wrap' with `position:absolute` and then it will work.

Comment: Wasn’t the desired output your requirement?

Comment: border, drop-shadow and box-shadow is must. Don't worry I will do by adding one more child.

Comment: @Abhishekkamal I see. Anyway it’s kind of an ambiguous requirement. Next time be more clear in the question you ask stating that you want to achieve the same functionality without manipulating the existing css. It’s gets easier for the contributor to focus on that.

Answer (score 0):

I just add another pseudo-element to display the text.

```css
input{
  min-width:350px;
  padding:10px;
}
.paswd_info_wrap.quick_note_error {
    background: #f77777;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    border-left: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    max-width:350px;
    font-size:1.2em
}
.paswd_info_wrap {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #efefef;
}
.paswd_info_wrap.quick_note_error:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 10px solid #ff000000;
    border-left: 10px solid #ffffff00;
    border-top: 10px solid #f77777;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    top: -10px;
    transform: rotate( 180deg);
    z-index: 10;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px red);
}
.paswd_info_wrap.quick_note_error::after {
    right: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    top: auto;
    left: calc(50% + 40px);
}
.quick_note_error::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 10px solid #ff000000;
    border-left: 10px solid #ffffff00;
    border-top: 10px solid #f77777;
    left: 0px;
    top: -10px;
    transform: rotate( 180deg);
    z-index: 10;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px red);
}

.paswd_err::after {
    content: 'Error';
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 24px;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: none;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 12px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px red);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="write password">
<div class="paswd_info_wrap quick_note_error">
  <div class="paswd_err">Password is not given correct.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! but I already knew this but I want to do this like I described in question description.